# Wicket URL with :: fails on Tomcat under MS Azure

Tags: tomcat, azure, wicket, azure-web-app-service

Processing custom wicket URL with :: fails on Tomcat on MS Azure.

URL looks like `./wicket/resource/com.evolveum.midpoint.web.security.MidPointApplication/::/::/::/::/::/webjars/adminlte/2.3.0/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min-ver-1444052020000.js` and it error 500 on IIS level before it reaches Tomcat.

Error message for abovementioned URL is:
`\\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\midpoint\wicket\resource\com.evolveum.midpoint.web.page.PageTemplate\::\web.config ( 0) :Cannot read configuration file`.

How to handle this? Add some expection to Azure IIS to skip wicket's URL? How?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom ResourceSettings#setParentFolderPlaceholder(String). It seems Azure has problems with the default `::`.

https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/d3abc0ec0432afedf11f44015cbb3170b49bab7c/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/settings/ResourceSettings.java#L632